# Join two tables with count from first table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I know there is an obvious answer to this question, but I'm like a noob trying to remember how to write queries.  I have the following table structure in Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 (
  accountid BIGINT NOT NULL, 
  rpt_start DATE NOT NULL, 
  rpt_end DATE NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY(accountid, rpt_start, rpt_end)
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE TABLE public.table2 (
  customer_id BIGINT NOT NULL, 
  read VARCHAR(255), 
  CONSTRAINT table2 PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

The objective of the query is to display a result set of accountid's, count of accountid's in table1 and read from table2.  The join is on table1.accountid = table2.customer_id.

The result set should appear as follows:

```
accountid     count     read
1234          2         100
1235          9         110
1236          1         91
```

The count column reflect the number of rows in table1 for each accountid.  The read column is a value from table2 associated with the same accountid.

Comment: I hope your actual schema has sensible names instead of `table1` and `table2`, and that you don't really join on `accountid = customer_id`.

Comment: I tried and failed to make sense of this: `The objective of the query is to display a result set of accountid's, count of accountid's in table1 and read from table2. The join is on table1.accountid = table2.customer_id.` Please provide sample values and what your result should look like. Also, as *always*, your version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, I removed actual names to protect the innocent.  Also, it just so happens that the accountid and customer_id are the same (legacy mainframe).

Comment: accountid      count      read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select accountid, "count", read
from
    (
        select accountid, count(*) "count"
        from table1
        group by accountid
    ) t1
    inner join
    table2 t2 on t1.accountid = t2.customer_id
order by accountid
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thank you!  I knew that I was missing a key concept.  This nailed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.customer_id, COUNT(*), table2.read
FROM table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table2.customer_id = table1.accountid)
GROUP BY table2.customer_id, table2.read
```

Comment: Thanks, but the trouble I'm having is including columns from both tables, as well as a count(*), in the result set.  The three columns in this answer are from the same table, i.e., table2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.customer_id, t2.read, COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.accountid = t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t2.customer_id, t2.read
    ;
```

Comment: Oops, upon inspection, I see that this trivial answer is almost identical to @Sn00k4h's